# Call PHP function in particular class via Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using Zend Framework.

I have PHP class as:

FileName : AdminController.php
Path : /admin/AdminController.php

**Ajax Function :**

```
function exportToExcel()
  {

  $.ajax({
  url: "/admin/AdminController/testFunction",
  type: "POST",
  success: function(output){
  alert("Sucess "+output);
  }
  });
 }
```

**PHP Class:**

```
class AdminController extends AbstractActionController
{
  public function testFunction()
  {
    return 'Its a test!!!';
  }
}
```

But i am not getting alert in sucess as:

```
Sucess Its a test!!!
```

What can be mistake?

How to call php function in particular phpclass/file???

Comment: What php framework are you using?

Comment: Did you try to setup router (I do not use Zend) for GET and check in browser url `/admin/AdminController/testFunction`? Do you see any response?

Comment: @Cheery sir, i get :  A 404 error occurred
Page not found.

Comment: But did you add path to the router?? As far as I see (and it is typical to Symfony, that I prefer) function from controllers are assigned in router and their name should end with Action

Comment: @Cheery means should i rename function name to testFunctionAction???

Comment: Look here http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.quick-start.html#create-a-route and here http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.quick-start.html#create-a-controller

Answer (score 1):

try

```
class AdminController extends AbstractActionController
{
  public function testFunction()
  {
    echo 'Its a test!!!';
  }
}
```

when you do 'return' the function returns the object, this is how you return data from models to your controllers, but when you need to send data to the client, here using  AJAX, you need to print the data.

**UPDATE**

try to open the url in browser, i.e. go to http://www.your.domain.com/admin/AdminController/testFunction and if the server is configerd as it should, you should see `Its a test!!!` on your screen. 
if you don't see it, follow [this guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.quick-start.html) to configure your server, especially the part about '[Create Route](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.quick-start.html#create-a-route)'

Comment: I want to return text to ajax from this function

Comment: Used echo just now, but no effect

Comment: what do you see when opening the url in browser?

Comment: nothing. I have a html button from which i am calling above javascript function and wanted to make ajax call to function in php class

Comment: @Kuf  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) example.com/admin/AdminController/testFunction

Comment: check out the links i've added to the bottom of the answer, if you follow that it will work. 404 means that the server is not configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try with full url in ajax call

```
 url: "http://example.com/admin/AdminController/testFunction",
```

Make sure you have setup routes for this.

Must be send back a output with `echo , print` or any printing method

```
public function testFunction() {
  echo 'Its a test!!!';
}
```

For more error check your **browser console** for errors

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://example.com/admin/AdminController/testFunction

Comment: @ÁngelDiMaría It means that you did not setup the correct route to this function. Methods of the class are not called by url, this is what framework is doing when you are telling it to do so.

Comment: @ÁngelDiMaría URL is not a route. In Zend Framework router is a class (or array in the framework's config), that makes correspondence between requested URL and Action Controller and method in it. I'm not sure that you looked at the Zend's manual.